# In which cases has a Wikipedia editor's identity been subpoenaed?

Tags: internet, privacy, identification, subpoena

In any jurisdiction, I'm looking for names of cases for either or ideally both of the following:

1. Where Wikipedia has been subpoenaed for information on an editor, complied with the subpoena, and provided non-public information on an editor.
2. Where an editor or Wikipedia itself has successfully challenged such a subpoena and nothing was ever revealed.

Since I don't think editors have to provide any information about themselves when they register, my guess is that any data resulting from a subpoena would probably be just a history of IP addresses used when logging in. The IPs would then be used to further attempt to identify the individual behind the username.

Comment: I can't give you names of cases (lawsuits), but I can point you to [this page in their 2H 2021 transparency report](https://wikimediafoundation.org/about/transparency/2021-2/requests-for-user-information/) and to [previous reports](https://wikimediafoundation.org/about/transparency/2021-2/previous-transparency-reports/), which may prove useful.

Comment: I remember only a single case from a few years back where an user got a "visit" from officers. But that user was vandalizing in really severe ways, harassing people, and breaking literally all the laws you can on the internet.